# Bending of a metal plate

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

If I have a stiff metal plate, and several forces acting on it at specific points, how would I calculate the resulting shape?

What information, besides the forces acting on it, would I need?

Comment: may be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus

Comment: It is necessary to set the boundary conditions at the edges of the plate.

Comment: Thank you, everyone for your comments and answers - it gives me plenty to investigate

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the shape and exact thickness of the plate, the material it is made from, its processing history (heat treatment, cold work, etc.), the points of application of the forces, and their magnitudes.

In the mechanical engineering field, calculations like this are routine and are typically handled by modeling programs that run inside any of the popular computer-aided design and drafting (CAD) packages that run on PC's. They will furnish detailed stress and deflection maps of the part in question as a function of loading.

Comment: Heat treatment does not affect the shape. Only the Modulus of Elasticity and Poisson's ratio affect the shape as far as mechanical properties. Heat treatment affects the strength, and it is used as a check against calculated stress values to predict yielding or breaking.

Comment: heat treatment affects the strength, as in the 7000 series of precipitation-hardening aluminum alloys. You must specify the tempering treatment to know its yield strength.

Comment: Yes, but the _op_ is asking about deflection. Heat treatment _does not_ affect deflection. The deflected shape is a function of $E$, $\nu$ and geometry.

Comment: heat treatment affects *strength* which affects *deflection under load*.

Comment: Strength is just a limit of stress. Like in a beam, deflection does not depend on strength so long as the part does not yield. $\delta = \frac{F \ell^3}{3 E I}$ is the standard equation for cantilever beam, and strength is not included. Strength is included in the safety factor calculation ${\rm SF} = \frac{S_y}{\sigma_{\rm VM}}$

Comment: The inputs to the modeling program which calculates for you the deflections include the yield stress. Exceeding this at any point in the part will set an error flag in the output file and warn you that the part will get bent.  I am done here; you are free to assert anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from geometric measures and material characteristics, then together with the forces applied, you need to specify how and where the plate is fixed.

Then, mainly according to the ratio of thickness wrt width / length, various approximated approaches can be taken, and we are speaking of [plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_theory) and [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_theory_of_shells).

Answer (score 1):

The math behind bending even simple cases with rectangular or circular plates is *very complex*.  You can look through the classic book of [Roark Formulas for Stress and Strain](http://160592857366.free.fr/joe/ebooks/Mechanical%20Engineering%20Books%20Collection/STRENGTH%20OF%20MATERIALS/Roark%27s%20Formulas%20For%20Stress%20And%20Strain.pdf) Chapter 11, page 451 to see for your self.

> In page 502, the simplest case of a rectangular plate is shown which is simply supported on all edges and a uniform load is applied perpendicular to the plate.
>
> [image: flat rectangular plates]
>
> The maximum deflection $y_{\rm max}$ is given as a function of geometry and material properties, but also with coefficient $\alpha$ which non-linearly depends on the aspect ratio $a/b$ of the plate.

As a result, engineers often rely on [FEA Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) that can handle far more complex shapes that analytically possible and give accurate but approximate results for deformations, stresses and reaction forces.

For example, a rectangular plate with a hole in it under uniform load is solved below using Autodesk Fusion 360  (free for personal use) and deflection results shown in color contours.

[image: Fusion360]

Comment: Thanks for the book reference!